# Divide by 2 and 9 php

Tags: php

Can you help me with this problem:

> Write a Boolean expression that checks for given integer if it can be
>   divided (without remainder) by 9 and 2 in the same time. Example: 
>   Divided by 9 and 2:
>   17-false ; 0 - false; 10 -false; 7-false; 18 -true; 72-true

Is it correct logic of my code ?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <?php

    if (72 % 9 == 0) {
        if (72 % 2 == 0) {
        }
        echo 'True.';
    }
    else {
        echo'False';
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tested the code? Does it work? If not - where does it fail?

Comment: Or in other words, can it be divided by 18.

Comment: Logic? Yes. Syntax? No.

Comment: `if(72 % (9 * 2) === 0) {}`

Comment: Look at the pairing of your `{`...`}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you thought in the right way, but that code won't work I think. Use this:

```
if (72 % 2 == 0 && 72 % 9 == 0) {
   echo "Correct";
} else {
   echo "Incorrect";
}
```

You can also check if the number is divisible by 2 * 9.